# Exponential moving average in J

Tags: moving-average, j, exp

I currently am going through some examples of J, and am trying to do an exponential moving average.

For the simple moving average I have done as follows:

```
sma =: +/%[
```

With the following given:

```
5 sma 1 2 3 4 5
1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2
```

After some more digging I found an example of the exponential moving average in q.

```
.q.ema:{first[y]("f"$1-x)\x*y}
```

I have tried porting this to J with the following code:

```
ema =: ({. y (1 - x)/x*y)
```

However this results in the following error:

```
domain error
|   ema=:({.y(1-x)    /x*y)
```

This is with `x = 20`, and `y` an array of 20 random numbers.

Comment: Why `sma =: +/%[`? `sma =: +%[` should do the same, no?

Comment: should sma be something like this, not tacit but this: `sma =: 4 : 'x (+/%#)\ y' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things that I notice that might help you out.

1) When you declare a verb explicitly you need to use the `:` Explicit conjunction and in this case since you have a dyadic verb the correct form would be `4 : 'x contents of verb y'` Your first definition of `sma =: +/%[` is tacit, since no `x` or `y` variables are shown.

```
ema =: 4 : '({. y (1 - x)/x*y)'
```

2) I don't know q, but in J it looks as if you are trying to Insert `/` a noun `1 - x` into a list of integers `x * y`. I am guessing that you really want to Divides `%`. You can use a gerunds as arguments to Insert but they are special nouns representing verbs and `1 - x` does not represent a verb.

```
ema =: 4 : '({. y (1 - x)%x*y)'
```

3) The next issue is that you would have created a list of numbers with `(1 - x) % x * y`, but at that point `y` is a number adjacent to a list of numbers with no verb between which will be an error. Perhaps you meant to use `y * (1 - x)%x*y` ?

At this point I am not sure what you want exponential moving average to do and hope the clues I have provided will give you the boost that you need.